# move uploaded file for ASP

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I know move the uploaded file in PHP

```
<?php
if( isset($_FILES["myfile"]) )
{
    $target = basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],"./temp/".$target))
    {
        $res = array("success"=>true,"file_name"=>$_FILES["myfile"]["name"],"size"=>$_FILES["myfile"]["size"]);
    }
    else
        $res = array("success"=>false,"desc"=>"no");
    echo json_encode($res);
}

?>
```

But I don't know the ASPX.

Now I need file upload code like PHP(above) in ASPX. 
any code to solve my problem?

Thank in advance.

Comment: asp.net webforms or mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

Just use the `FileUpload.SaveAs(...)` function to save the uploaded file where you want on the server

Answer (score 0):

Change the file location

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
 <%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <Script language="VB" runat="server">
 Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim f As String
    Dim file
    For Each f In Request.Files.AllKeys
        file = Request.Files(f)
        Dim filepather As String = Server.MapPath("/pic/") + file.FileName
        file.SaveAs(filepather) 'Server.MapPath("/pic") + file.FileName)
    Next f

  End Sub

 </Script>


 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```